# Convexity, linearity and their combination for MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, convex, linearity

I'm going through Murphy's ML a Probabilistic Perspective book and in chapter 9 we have the following excerpt talking about the MLE of exponential family distributions:

[image: exponential family MLE]

My question is: How do we arrive at the conclusion that because -A(θ) is concave in θ and $\mathbf{\theta}^T\phi(D)$ is linear in θ, their difference will also be concave?

What's the relationship between concavitiy and linearity here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-A$ is concave if
$$
-\alpha A(\boldsymbol\theta_1) - (1-\alpha)A(\boldsymbol\theta_2) \leq -A(\alpha\boldsymbol\theta_1 + (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol\theta_2)
$$
for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, and $\boldsymbol\theta_1, \boldsymbol\theta_2$ in the domain of $A$.

On the other hand
$$
\alpha(\boldsymbol\theta_1^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) - A(\boldsymbol\theta_1)) + (1-\alpha)(\boldsymbol\theta_2^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) - A(\boldsymbol\theta_2)) 
$$

$$
=\alpha\boldsymbol\theta_1^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) - \alpha A(\boldsymbol\theta_1) + (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol\theta_2^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) -(1-\alpha) A(\boldsymbol\theta_2)
$$

$$
=\alpha\boldsymbol\theta_1^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) + (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol\theta_2^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) - \alpha A(\boldsymbol\theta_1) -(1-\alpha) A(\boldsymbol\theta_2)
$$

$$
\leq (\alpha\boldsymbol\theta_1 + (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol\theta_2) ^T\phi(\mathcal{D}) - A(\alpha\boldsymbol\theta_1 + (1-\alpha)\boldsymbol\theta_2)
$$

The last inequality is easily verified, as the first addend of the last line is linear and the second one corresponds to the inequality we proposed initially.

Comment: Re. "the first addend of the last line is linear" that has to do with the fact that it is also convex and concave, thereby the equality holds, while for the second addend we get the inequality from the definition, correct? Also linear in θ I guess is the important part here.

Comment: A function f is said to be linear (in the algebraic sense) if $f(ax +by) = af(x)+bf(y)$. Therefore, the last inequality would be an equality if we ditched the terms involving the function $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship is that a linear function is both convex and concave, so we have that $\theta^T \phi(D)$ is concave, and $-NA(\theta)$ is concave. Thus the loglikelihood is a sum of two concave functions, which is a concave function (that one is an easy proof).

For completeness, let us write out the proof that a sum of two concave functions is concave.  Let $f,g$ be concave on their common domain $D$.  Then, by definition of concavity, we have that $f(\alpha x +(1-\alpha) y) \ge \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)$, for all $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and $x,y \in D$, likewise for $g$.  Then we can compute 
\begin{align} 
(f+g)(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) &= f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) +g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) \\
     &\le \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y) + \alpha g(x) + (1-\alpha) g(y) \\
   &=  \alpha (f+g)(x) + (1-\alpha) (f+g) (y)
\end{align}
showing indeed that the susm $f+g$ is concave.

Comment: Right, I was missing the part that a linear function is both convex and concave, thanks!